# Kubernetes Secret Environment Variable - 2+ deployments not equal

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, environment-variables, base64

I'm having an issues with env var comparisons (this is all example data).

I am setting my environment vars as secrets as shown, base64 encoded:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-password
type: Opaque
data:
  SUPER_SECRET_PW: cGFzc3dvcmQK
```

In my deployment YAML, I can setting the env var as shown:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
      - name: SUPER_SECRET_PW
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: secret-password
            key: SUPER_SECRET_PW
```

I have tried other `envFrom` approaches too, but it doesn't seem to work too well with multiple env vars?

The issue is that the env var is set in 2 different deployments, and my application says that the values are different. The services talk to eachother perfectly, the env var values show up the exact same in `minikube dashboard`, and when I hard code the value as shown, it works perfectly:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
      - name: SUPER_SECRET_PW
        value: password
```

What is the init flow for the secrets -> env vars when the deployment is run, could that be a potential timing issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add exactly what's the POD error from the logs

```bash
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE logs $YOUR_POD
```

But since you need to use a secret in your deployment, I'd start by creating the secret first:

```bash
kubectl -n dev create secret generic secret-password \
    --from-literal=SUPER_SECRET_PW=cGFzc3dvcmQK
```

Check your secret is well created:

```bash
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get secret secret-password
```

Now, in your deployment file, add your environnement variable from the secret:

```yaml
# deployment.yml
...
        env:
          - name: SUPER_SECRET_PW
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: secret-password
                key: SUPER_SECRET_PW

...
```

And, pay attention for spaces and tabs in your `yml` file

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!

I have tried pulling the secret that way too! The issue is reported from the service it's communicating with saying that the ENV VAR is not the same (but when the value is hardcoded in both deployments, it works perfectly).

I have also SSH'd into the service to make sure the env var was set correctly - it is, so that's where my confusion lies

Comment: What's the error from the logs of your Pods ?

Answer (score 0):

I used `echo password | base64`

Which returned the password in base64 notation with a return character at the end because of the `echo`.

Plugged `password` into an online base64 encoder instead, application works perfectly now!